# If state is immutable, is the whole state replaced on any change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

If `state` is immutable wouldn't the whole state need to be replaced on any change? Otherwise, you're mutating the state. Are top-level keys held as separate immutable objects?

By definition wouldn't any change need to replace the whole thing? How is this handled by Redux? Wouldn't replacing the full state break PureComponents?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Well, state is replaced because it's immutable, but only reducer's slice of state. The reducer doesn't recreate *the whole store*, just it's own slice when calculating next state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down step by step:

1. There is an initial redux store of { color: 'red' }
2. The user clicks a button
3. An action is generated, say CHANGE_COLOR
4. Redux calls your reducer with the store (from step 1) and the action. The reducer returns a new store, say { color: 'blue' }

Then, let's say you had a `class Square extends PureComponent` with `mapStateToProps` as `(store) => { color: store.color }`

What happens now is that when the store changes, `redux-react` runs the mapStateToProps every time. It then generates new props. These props get sent to react.

If you're with me so far the TL;DR of how redux and react work together is that whenever the redux store changes, every single mapStateToProps runs and this generates new props for your react components.

From this point on, it's standard React. When the props of a React component change, it runs `componentWillReceiveProps` followed by `shouldComponentUpdate`.

For a `PureComponent`, basically that means shouldComponentUpdate just does a shallow equality check on your new props, and goes from there.

---

Okay, with this base understanding out of the way, nested objects behave similarly.

Instead of a store of `{color: 'red'}` what if we had a store like this:

```
{
  allMyData: {
    color: 'red'
    key1: 'someData',
    key2: 'lotsMoreData',
    bigData: {
     nestedKey: 'EvenMoreNestedData',
    }

}
```

Then, your reducer might look something like this:

```
const reducer = (store, action) => {
  if (action == CHANGE_COLOR) {
    let newStore = Object.assign({}, store);
    newStore.allMyData = Object.assign({}, newStore.allMyData, { color: 'blue' });

  }
}
```

Note that there are better tools to do deep immutable merges. One main point I want to show here is that although the `newStore` is a different object, both `store` and `newStore` BOTH point to the *SAME* `bigData` key and the other values that are unchanged. The immutability part allows for this kind of thing to work.

After this, the steps are basically the same. After every store change, `mapStateToProps` runs and generates a new props object. Redux-react then passes that new prop object to React and in this case, a `PureComponent` wouldn't render if the prop values have the same identity (`===`)

Note that redux-react has some perf optimizations where it will avoid calling into react with new props but for the purposes of this discussion I'm omitting that step.

Hope this helps clear up your questions.

TL;DR: Every redux action returns a new store. Every time a new store is generated, mapStateToProps generates new props for every `connect`ed react component. If the react component is a pureComponent, it won't re-render because the props haven't changed.

The crux for your question is that because your store is immutable, you can re-use the same inner objects across different stores, and even pass *those* into your react components via mapStateToProps.

Comment: If this was helpful consider upvoting the answer and marking it correct :-) @Yeah

Comment: I tried to upvote but couldn't because my account is new, sorry about that. 

One follow up question, in redux if your action/reducer updated `foo.bar` and your connected component `mapStateToProps` was `(store) => { foo: store.foo }` and then passed `foo={foo}` to a PureComponent child. The child wouldn't rerender when `foo.bar` changes, right? That's why they recommend keeping things as flat as possible? thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Redux never says that the state is immutable. It says the reducers which constitute the store or state of the application should be immutable and should be pure functions.
Yes the top level keys are seperately considered to be immutable.
So on any change or in Redux terms any action is done we trigger a reducer on each action which causes the state change.